# How to apply workspace manifest to root package

Tags: rust-cargo

I have a cargo workspace with a root package (the opposite of a virtual workspace). In the root `Cargo.toml`, I'd like to apply the workspace manifest to the root package. However, this seems impossible. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my testing, it seems like the root package is treated as an entirely separate package. Its dependencies are declared separately and the only similarity it has with the workspace is that they both use the same `Cargo.toml` file. The root package has its own `[dependencies]` section and everything. This feels unintuitive to me. Is there a way to apply the same manifest across all packages within a workspace regardless of its nesting?